# Block with entities referenced in a field from current node (of different type)

Tags: 8, blocks

I got 2 different types  of content (**Place** & **Event**).
When an **Event** is created you can define **Place** (one or more) where this **Event** will happened (**Place** are referenced in a field in **Event**).

With View, I can display a block with the **Event** attached to the current **Place**. But I can't display in a block the **Place** of the current **Event** (on its page).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add relationship Entity Reference: Referenced Entity for field which is referencing to Place content type and you will see the Place field in fields.

Hope this will help.
[image]

Comment: It's weird cause I don't have the option "Entity Reference: Referenced Entity" in "Add a relationships" on D8. But I have  "Content referenced from field_that_place" and I'm turning around it without success that's why I finally asked how to do it...